# ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time version (7.79.1) is older than compile-time version (7.84.0)

Tags: python, macos, pip, openssl, python-poetry

I know this question has been asked before am I have tried most of the solutions and still having issues. So, I am on Mac OS Monterey (12.6.1). Installed Python 3.7.12 (using pyenv). Using Poetry for dependency management. I did the below steps after activating & deactivating the virtual environment using poetry (`source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate`)

1. Removed existing pycurl using brew
2. Installed openssl (`brew install openssl`)
3. Verified ssl installation directory

```
  brew --prefix openssl
  /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3

  $ ls -la /usr/local/opt/openssl@3
  lrwxr-xr-x  1 xxxxxx  admin  25 14 Dec 22:57 /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3 -> ../Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.7
```

4. Install PyCurl specifying inline the above `openssl` install directories like this

```
  PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include" pip install --no-cache-dir pycurl
```

PyCurl installs without any problem but when I try to import pyCurl I get the following error message.

```
Python 3.7.12 (default, Dec 14 2022, 22:00:27)
[Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pycurl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time version (7.79.1) is older than compile-time version (7.86.0)
>>> quit()
```

PS:

1. `poetry env info --path` does return the correct poetry virtual env path.
2. I tried switching my Python version to 3.8.X and 3.9.X and still having the same issue.
3. I also updated my curl version to 7.86 using brew and doing a `brew --version` does conform the same.

```
$ curl --version                                                                                                                                                                                     ✔  at 11:13:19 pm  ▓▒░
curl 7.86.0 (aarch64-apple-darwin21.6.0) libcurl/7.86.0 (SecureTransport) OpenSSL/1.1.1s zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.2 libidn2/2.3.4 libssh2/1.10.0 nghttp2/1.51.0 librtmp/2.3
Release-Date: 2022-10-26
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

What am I missing from the above steps? Thank you in advance for your time... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and errors I managed to find a way around this. The easiest way for me was to download curl and manually set the path for PyCurl compilation. Following were the steps I did to resolve my issue

```
$> pip uninstall pycurl
$> brew uninstall curl

# Install openssl to compile pycurl
$> brew install openssl@3

# If you already have openssl@3 installed run the following
# command and note the path of LDFLAGS an CPPFLAGS
$> brew info openssl@3

# Downloading latest version of Pycurl
# I downloaded curl to my HOME path
$> wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.86.0.tar.bz2

# Unzip 
$> tar -xf curl-7.86.0.tar.bz2

#Add the following to .zshrc
export PATH="$(HOME)/curl-7.86.0/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/curl-7.86.0/lib -L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$HOME/curl-7.86.0/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include"

# Install PyCurl
$> pip install --no-cache-dir --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl

#Checking if the installation went right
$> python -c "import pycurl"
```

Since I was using Poetry the above steps did not add PyCurl to my virtual env. I went into my project, activated my virtual env (`source $(poetry env info --path)/bin/activate`) and then ran `pip install --no-cache-dir --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl`

Hope this helps !!!.

Answer (score 0):

If you stuck with error `pycurl: libcurl link-time version (7.86.0) is older than compile-time version (7.87.0)`, here is updated and slightly changed solution May 2023 for MacOS Ventura (thanks @Vinnie):

```bash
# Remove installed version
pip uninstall -y pycurl

# Install openssl for pycurl compiling
brew install openssl || brew update openssl

# Downloading sources
cd <your_project_folder>
curl https://curl.se/download/curl-7.86.0.tar.bz2 -o curl-7.86.0.tar.bz2
tar -xf curl-7.86.0.tar.bz2

# Setting up temporary compiler flags and PATH
export PATH="$(pwd)/curl-7.86.0/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L$(pwd)/curl-7.86.0/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I$(pwd)/curl-7.86.0/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@3/include"

# Option --install-option="--with-openssl" is deprecated in pip version 23.X.
# So downgrade to version 22.X. Not cool, but works.
pip install pip==22

# Installing curl
pip install --no-cache-dir --compile --install-option="--with-openssl" pycurl
```

To keep this answer up-to-date here is a hint: you should download curl version defined in a first part of error message, for example `libcurl link-time version (7.86.0)`